# Building endpoint values from a function - The value for annotation attribute X must be a constant expression

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, rest

I am trying to build an endpoint value from a a string built by a function, as shown below:

**ManagerController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/manager/")
public class ManagerController {
    @Autowired
    Manager manager;

    public String endpointBuilder(String str) {
        return "storage/" + str;
    }

    public String storeEndpoint = endpointBuilder("{store}");

    @PostMapping(value = storeEndpoint)
    private ResponseEntity<?> storeSomething(String str) {
        manager.storeSomething(str);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(CREATED);
    }
}
```

The line `@PostMapping(value = storeEndpoint)` results in the error `The value for annotation attribute PostMapping.value must be a constant expression`.  A project I am working on has a large amount of similar endpoint names and would benefit from me being able to use `endpointBuilder()`, especially to keep names uniform between the REST controller and its unit tests, but I am stuck at figuring out how to make it work.  The rest of this example code is given below.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

**Manager.java**

```
@Component
public class Manager {
    private List<String> storage;

    @Autowired
    public Manager() {
        this.storage = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void storeSomething(String str) {
        storage.add(str);
    }
}
```

How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do, if it is possible?  If it is not possible, is there an alternate way to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. From [JLS, §9.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1):

> An element type `T` is commensurate with an element value `V` if and only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - `T`is an array type `E[]` and either:
>
>   - `V` is an ElementValueArrayInitializer and each ElementValue (analogous to a VariableInitializer in an array initializer) in `V` is commensurate with `E`; or
>   - `V` is an ElementValue that is commensurate with `E`.
> - The type of `V` is assignment compatible (§5.2) with `T`, and furthermore:
>
>   - If `T` is a primitive type or `String`, and `V` is a constant expression (§15.28).
>   - `V` is not null.
>   - If `T` is `Class`, or an invocation of `Class`, and `V` is a class literal (§15.8.2).
>   - If `T` is an enum type, and `V`is an enum constant.

In essence, only compile-time constants are permitted as values for annotation-elements.